# Pairing wireless routers

Tags: wifi

Apologies if there is a better site.

I have DAP-1360 and another router connected to an office switch, which connect to the internet router.

I would like the two wireless devices to act as access points, but to be seen as the same network (there is an area of overlap of the signal).

DAP-1360 supports: AP Mode, Wireless Client Mode, repeater, bridge, bridge with AP, WISP client router and WISP repeater mode out of the box.

My requirements are satisfied with WISP repeater mode, however in this scenario (I assume, I did not run traceroute) the nodes communicate wirelessly between themselves, too, and there is available router over wire.

Related question that seem to have an answer is [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/33864/how-can-i-set-up-a-single-wireless-network-through-a-number-of-wifi-routers). The answer is from 2009 and I was wondering if it is still the case that different channels and same ssid is a recommended, standard solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure them in AP mode and then do what the answer on that link says. I.e.:

> Just set each router to use the same SSID but a different channel.
>   Users will see it as a single wireless network when they move between
>   floors. The different channels will ensure that the routers do not
>   conflict with each other.

And that should be the lot.